# CYK (Cocke-Younger-Kasami) Grammar Rules

Tags: c#, nlp, pos-tagger, cyk

I am interested in Natural Language Parsing and have written a Brill Part of Speech Tagger, and would like to enhance it by combining it with a a POS tagger based on grammar rules. Is anyone aware of open source ruleset files for English anywhere? I am particularly interested in anything related to the CYK (Cocke-Younger-Kasami) algorithm, C# especially. Thanks.

Comment: I thought that statistical methods using a codex had swept away all other approaches to the problem.  Grammars seem so 90s now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk)?

They seem to have a Brill-based POS tagger with [lexicons and rules](http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/code/HEAD/tree/gate/trunk/plugins/ANNIE/resources/heptag/). It's implemented in Java so you should probably understand the code easily. It is available in the same project at sourceforge. Here is their [POS tagger documentation](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch6.html#sec%3aannie%3atagger).

Hope this helps.

Off topic, [lectures from Michael Collins](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/notes-spring2013.html) on POS tagging and theory behind it.